# Cannot send email to CRM queue owned by team

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We've setup the CRM Email Router to deliever emails from a POP3 account to the CRM Server. The email address the external user is sending to belongs to a queue.

When the queue is owned by a user, the everything work and the mail is delivered. (hence we know the email server is working and the CRM permissions are correct)

When we change the queue owner to a team, we get the error below. We've checked that SID mentioned in the error, and it references the correct team, which is probably why the system cannot find the entry in the user table.

Any ideas on how to fix this? We've already using Rollup 10.

> *An error occurred while delivering the e-mail message with subject "Monday incoming testing" in mailbox foo@foo.local for delivery to
>   [exchange].
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]:
>   systemuser With Id = 9f3926f4-aaf7-e111-87b9-005056265c17 Does Not
>   Exist (Fault Detail is equal to
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).**

Comment: We have seen this same error on RU8 versions as well. If you figure it out, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that the team did not have the correct permissions. Everything started working again once we restored the default permissions for the team.

The error message was just misleading... :(